# Large volume email sent, avoid duplication

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing issue in schedule sending of email.Let me explain.Since php has no multi threading, i have decided to run 3 scripts(a1.php,a2.php,a3.php, all are same) in same time on same table.
Table: email_job
id:unique but not incemental(random) text field
email_text: text field
status:pending/sent
update_time:datetime field
When i read 100 email(status=pending) to send using a1.php, same time another 2(a2.php,a3.php)scripts also reading same 100 email for sending since status=pending.
Some times 3 script read same data , so duplicate email sent.
is it possible to lock data in read level, suppose a1.php read that 50 rows and lock these rows untill status changed, so other script will read other rows in pending status and not locked rows...
How can i prevent duplicate sending, i need to use many scripts since i need to send many email in second?
Note: i m using php,mysql, if possible give code. Here may be email/sms/others for large volume send in short time.

Comment: Certainly you can implement a locking strategy. But to send mass SPAM messages usually it is a far better idea to use a professional service like Mandrill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a column to your table as follows.

```
 processed_by int(11) not null default 0
```

Then, each of your processing scripts can run this loop:

1. `update table set processed_by = CONNECTION_ID() where processed_by = 0 limit 1`
2. `select * from table where processed_by = CONNECTION_ID()`
3. handle the row in the table (send the email, whatever)
4. `update table set processed_by = -CONNECTION_ID() where processed_by = CONNECTION_ID()`

You break out of the loop when step one returns a row count of zero (meaning there are no unprocessed entries in the table.

Rows in your table with `processed_by` values of zero are pending processing. Rows with a positive value are presently active in processing, and rows with a negative value are complete.

Step 1 chooses just one row to process. It does so in a way that scales up to an unlimited number of scripts running in parallel: every script has its own CONNECTION_ID value.

**Edit**, in a comment you specified a throughput of 100K messages per minute. That's very large, especially if it is the 24x7 base load requirement. It's going to take a lot of work to scale your SMTP server infrastructure to handle this kind of load.

The capacity of my suggested solution can be scaled up; I specified batches of size one. Larger batches will work. Here's a modification of my suggestion.

1. `update table set processed_by = CONNECTION_ID() where processed_by = 0 limit 500`
2. If no rows were affected by the `UPDATE` request, sleep for a few seconds.
3. `select * from table where processed_by = CONNECTION_ID()`
4. For each row in that result set,

   - process the row (sending the message, whatever).
5. `update table set processed_by = -CONNECTION_ID() where processed_by = CONNECTION_ID()`

This works because the UPDATE request in step one is free of race conditions when used by multiple programs connecting to the same database server.

In the comments somebody suggested using a bulk email service (like Mandrill). That is a good suggestion: you're paying for their expertise at getting messages delivered reliably all over the place.  Mandrill offers a free tier with up to 12,000 messages per month.

Comment: Our target is to send 1lac in aminute(sms/email).if we run multiple scripts so we need to lock that rows already read by one script.for that when we read 400 rows then instantly updating flag is_lock=1, after process complete is_lock=0. But problem is when same time others script do same then my technique can not avoid the issue(in ms difference other script may read at least 100 rows duplicate). I need if one script read some 400 rows which is not sent, then others script need to read some other rows which is not sent till now to avoid overlapping.Will your suggestion solve this issue?

Comment: Please see my edit. I assume you are aware that you'll need approved-mailer authentication for this volume of emails.  Read up on DKIM and SPF.  For example. https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582267-What-are-SPF-and-DKIM-and-how-do-I-set-them-up-

Comment: we are sending sms via api.No matter volume, problem is duplicate sending, we need to avoid it(some time.. using  cronjob, may multiple instances of same script reading same data suddenly.)

Comment: i just check with your code to avoid duplication for multiple instances,it seems success and your code is right as per test, let me check little 1 more check then i will make it answer

Comment: Yes, working. is it possible to gain same target using php session, connection_id?

Comment: You asked:  is it possible to gain same target using php session, connection_id?  I don't understand what you mean here.

Comment: addon: pls also try to solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413652/about-schedule-send-large-volume-in-time-using-php

Answer (score 0):

Add a `visited` flag on your db entry.

Every script needs to read the flag before an entry is processed, and set it to `1` if it is `0`, so the other scripts omit the entry.